# Default Value in Select and MenuItem of MUI

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, dropdown, menuitem

i have a edit form with filled input , the values are shown on textField accordingly but on DropDown it's not showing default value , [[check Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reuQj.png)] , [[check other Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfqhZ.png)]

```
 <Select
                  name="active"
                  labelId="active-label"
                  id="active"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={values.active}
                  defaultValue={values.active}
                  error={touched.active && Boolean(errors.active)}
                >
                 
                  <MenuItem value={true}>Yes</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={false}>No</MenuItem>
                </Select>
```

i just want to display this default value too , it can be solved if i used option insted of meanuItem but option will not display dropdown items as i want check my code below and image for display [dropdown with option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1in2.jpg)

```
 <Select
             native
              name="active"
              labelId="active-label"
              id="active"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.active}
              defaultValue={values.active}
            > 
              <option value={true} >Yes</option>
              <option value={false}>No</option>
            </Select>
```

the code for user binding with values :

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
async function getData(id) {
const fetchedUser = await fetch(`${state.baseUrl}users/${id}`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${state.loginToken}`,
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((err) => console.error(err)); 

setUser(fetchedUser);} 


 useEffect(() => {
    getData(id);
  }, []);

const initialValues = {
    fullName: user.fullname,
    email: user.email,
    userName: user.username,
    organ: String(user.organization),
    password: "",
    role: String(user.role),
    active: user.is_active};
```

Comment: what does `values` have ? I guess you can do as `defaultValue={String(values.active)}` and have the `value` attribute for `MenuItem` as strings as `value = {"true"}` and `value = {"false"}`

Comment: @KcH i have updated the code , just menuitem are not working with native select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- usually `defaultValue` is used for uncontrolled component
- you can have the `boolean` values for `MenuItem` here as `string` as all the values in `DOM` are strings in general

---

```
<Select
  name="active"
  labelId="active-label"
  id="active"
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  defaultValue={values.active.toString()}  // must match type of value so (convert to string / number)
  error={touched.active && Boolean(errors.active)}
>
      <MenuItem value={true}>Yes</MenuItem>  // value must be string or number
      <MenuItem value={false}>No</MenuItem>  // value must be string or number
</Select>;
```

Comment: yeah i already did this but i want to use menuitem not option but it's not working with nativeSelect

Comment: usually `defaultValue` is used for uncontrolled component .... so you have to remove the `value` on `Select` attributes to get that work ... see the e.g. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cybhuu?file=demo.tsx%3AL16)

Comment: yeah it worked but it always show default value false

Comment: In that case you can have the `value` prop and doesn't need any `defaultValue` at all being a controlled component - [check this e.g. from docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Comment: i convert my values.action to Boolean and it worked now

Answer (score 1):

What is your issue, default value is not getting displayed if you use MenuItem  and if you use option then default value is getting display, but the Styling of the Options is old one if I am it's all about default value then please try the below  code

if values object is like

```
  const values = {
    active: true,
  };
```

Then the below code will be

```
<Box>
  <Select
    name="active"
    labelId="active-label"
    id="active"
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    value={values.active}
    sx={{ width: "10rem" }}
  >
    <MenuItem value={true}>Yes</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={false}>No</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</Box>
```

below containe image
[image]

[image]

Comment: ok so it worked but i dont have active object it's object of user that's coming from get api call then i set user values

Comment: Can you share that user Object with me?

Comment: And for Api call what r u using I will be great if you use useQuery because when ypu use useQuery you get loading, data and many more options and when user dat gets change it with automatically set the value object for you, let me know what is it in your case.

Comment: Ok then after getting the data you will set values as user right and in that user object there will be "active" key with boolean value as true/ value or Yes/ No that you need to confirm if we have yes or no then just change the <MenuItem value={yes}/> and if true or false then take the above example there is noting difference it will work let me know.

Comment: i have set default value as user.is_active (that i have in my user state) but it kept null so i make a condition **defaultValue={user.is_active ? true : false}** it will always set false although i have true/false value in user.is_active

Comment: after getting the user it's not setting the default value

Comment: you must me using formik form right in that u must me setting initialValues, so you can set initials value as per form which means even if you have is_active can can set initalsValues = { active: user.is_active ? user.is_active :false,} and pass this initialsValues in formik the above initialValue.active mean even if it is null it will take false as by default value and if it is not null then it will take what user.is_active contain

Comment: it wroked !! thanks alot

Comment: Only you need set defaultvalue to initial state